# Firebase Push notifications not working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

So my Firebase push notifications are not working on iOS (Simulator + I do not have a developer account, might this be already a reason?)

What I did:

- Created an app in Google Firebase (I think I didn't add the fingerprint because I don't have it yet)
- Added Firebase/FirebaseMessaging to my Podfile
- Added GoogleService-Info.plist to my project Directory
- Added Keychain Sharing in Capabilities
- Added following code to my App Delegate:

Here is my code:

```
import Firebase
import UserNotifcations
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert, .sound] {(granted, error) in}
         application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

         return true;

     }

}
```

Any mistakes? Did I miss something? Is it because I don't have a developer account or is the simulator not capable of receiving push notifications? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you've uploaded the developer certificate to firebase if you're still testing it. If you've only uploaded the production certificate push notifications will not work while you're testing.

Answer (score 3):

Simulators in Xcode don't receive remote notifications. You have to run it on an actual device. I think Apple allow you to run it on a device without a paid developer account now.

Answer (score 2):

You won' be able to send push notifications without a paid developer account. Not even on a real device.

More information [here](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/)

Answer (score 1):

The iOS simulator can't receive remote notifications. You have to run the app on your device.